# convert HTML to Adobe InDesign file?

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign

my client wants to create the Adobe InDesign file basing on the HTML text (in the ASP.NET MVC 3 project). I'm totally new in the InDesign and I'm wondering if it is even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This project on google code may be of some help to you. It uses xslt to transform xhtml to an idml file that can be imported into InDesign.

http://code.google.com/p/ickmull/